# Factory Template : iostream vs string

Tags: templates, c++14, factory

Template compilation fail without including "string" header even if i add "iostream" header !

```
//----------------------------------------------------------
// Header : Factory.h
//----------------------------------------------------------
template <typename TKey, typename TObject>
class Factory
{
public :
    std::map<TKey, TObject*> m_mapReference;
    void Register(TKey key,TObject *obj){
        if(m_mapReference.find(key)==m_mapReference.end())
            m_mapReference[key]=obj;
    }
};

class A
{ };

class B : public A
{ };

//----------------------------------------------------------
// Main.cpp
//----------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
//#include <string>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string strType = "B";
    B b;
    Factory< string, A > fact;
    fact.Register(strType, &b);
}
```

vc\include\xfunctional(125): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Hash<_Traits> &,const std::_Hash<_Traits> &)' : impossible de déduire l'argument modèle pour 'const std::_Hash<_Traits> &' à partir de 'const std::string'

Comment: If you use `std::string` you should include `<string>`. Why do you find this surprising?

Comment: Igor Tandetnik : im surprising because u can write : include <iostream>, using namespace std, and use string in code. Why in my code this two are not suffisent ?!

Comment: Well, clearly, you cannot - or you wouldn't be here asking this question. Your code fails to compile, does it not?

Comment: Igor Tandetnik : my code compile when i use : include <string>. What is the difference between using string variable in this two cases : (1) by including <string>  |  (2) by including <iostream>

Comment: The code compiles when you include `<string>` and doesn't when you include `<iostream>`. Is this not difference enough? I'm not sure I understand what you are driving at with this line of questioning.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik : The following code works well : `#include  <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
 string str("Hello Igor!");
 cout<<str.c_str()<<endl;
 return 0;
}`
Why this code works fine WITHOUT includind <string> and my Original code dont work without   `#include  <string>` ?!

Comment: Your original code [compiles for me](https://rextester.com/LGS63068), once I add the missing `#include <map>`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ok, thanks for your test. The original code does not compile on my machine. I discovered something in the previous example (Hello Igor !). IF i don't put `#include <string>` I CAN NOT use `cout<<str<<endl;`  (WITHOUT caling c_str()). I think that including <string> has some relation with operator overloading this is why it dosent work in my ORiginal code

Answer (score 0):

I think you have discovered an "accidental include". The implementation of  needed some functionality of std::string so needed to include , and so the definition of std::string is visible "accidentally".

You should not rely on such accidental includes, though there is no way to know for sure that you have not done so. It may well be that on another platform, or a different implementation of the standard library, or even just a new version of the standard library, that  no longer needs or includes .